# Magento Admin Tab ACL issue

Tags: magento, tabs, admin, acl

Ive added a tab to the admin system->config backend...something i have done before without issue.
For some reason, i am getting a 404 when i try access the tab (even though the 'tab' config contents are displayed on the DEFAULT view when go into system->configuration).

Ive been playing with the ACL...adding the code to the config.xml file, and alos trying to create a seperate adminhtml.xml file.....but it wont kick in.
Please could someone look over my config code, and see where im going wrong. I think i just cant see it...code blind...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Mworkz_Mavp>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Mworkz_Mavp>
</modules>
<global>
    <!-- 
    <blocks>
        <micoavp><class>Mworkz_Micoavp_Block</class></micoavp>
        <catalog>
            <rewrite>
                    <product_view_type_configurable>Bsm_Micoavp_Block_Configurable</product_view_type_configurable>
            </rewrite>
        </catalog>
    </blocks>

    <events>
            <catalog_product_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <micoavp>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Mworkz_Micoavp_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>Add_CustomOptions_Automatically</method>
                    </micoavp>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_save_after>
     </events>
       -->  
</global>
<frontend>  
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <mworkz_mavp>
                <file>mworkz_mavp.xml</file>
            </mworkz_mavp>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
<adminhtml>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <all>
                <title>Allow Everything</title>
            </all>
            <admin>  <!--This is acl based on URL. If you see URL it would be /admin/system_config/ -->
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                           <config>
                                <children>
                                        <mavp translate="title">  <!-- This is name of the section created by us -->
                                            <title>Mico AVP ACL</title>  <!-- Title as shown in User->Roles->Permissions Window -->
                                            <sort_order>99</sort_order>
                                        </mavp>
                                 </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</adminhtml>
```

thanks in advance....
Shaun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using the subsection name (avp), not the section name (mworkz).

so change:

```
<mavp translate="title">  ...  </avp>
```

to:

```
<mworkz translate="title">  ...  </mworkz>
```

Comment: Thanks!  Was going crazy over this, and all I got when searching was "try logging out and in again" on the 404. Didn't even notice that it was showing on the default config view at first.